# Unable to set the right keyboard layout in Ubuntu 16.04 with "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration"

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, keyboard, dpkg, keyboard-layout

I want to set the keyboard layout to the standard US international in an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 machine I am accessing through Vultr (only have a command line, no GUI).

I have tried more than 10 US keyboard configurations that are given to me after running "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration", most of them from the model "Generic 105-key (Intl) PC". This is driving me crazy as I can only find layouts that have arrows (">", "<") or pipes ("|"), not both, so I need to be constantly changing layout.

EDIT:
Seems like users of Digital Ocean are having the same issue:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-type-some-symbols-on-console

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard settings

```
Go to Ubuntu settings
Click on <Text Entry> 
Click on <Allow different sources for each window>
Click on < New windows use the default source>
```

Now the Keyboard settings will return to normal keys for characters like @ and £ etc.

John Smith from Poplar London UK. Date 29/11/2018

Comment: How do you click when you **only have a command line, no GU**?